# Byte containing 2 signed nibbles to 2 signed integers

Tags: java

For some reason, I couldn't find any answer to this question on StackOverflow. If it's already been answered, kindly point me to a duplicate post. Thanks!

I have a device that delta encodes a signal and packs 2 4-bit deltas into a `byte`. I'm trying to decode the signal in Java by separating the upper and lower 4 bits of the `byte` into two separate, signed `ints`.

For example:

```java
byte packedByte = (byte) 0x0FF; // should represent the value -1, -1 in twos complement

int upper = packedByte >> 4; // upper byte is easy, prints -1

/*
 * A few goes at getting the lower 4 bits:
 */
int lower = packedByte & 0x0F; // sign is not extended, prints 15
lower = (packedByte << 4) >> 4; // doesn't work for positive values
lower = (byte)((byte)(packedByte << 4) >>> 4); // works, but this feels slow
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the 4-bit nybbles are _signed_? This would give you a range of +7 to -8.

Comment: Yes, I am the one doing the signing. They need to be signed because deltas can be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, as Jim Garrison points out, your nibbles really only represent -8 up to positive 7, you can keep doing what you were doing tof the upper, and you can do the following for the lower: `(packedByte & 0x0F)-2*(packedByte & 0x08)`. The logic here is that it leaves 0 to 7 alone (subtracts 0 from it), but if there is a 1 in the sign bit of the lower number, it subtracts 2*8 which is 16 to get the appropriate negative number.

Comment: Or if you don't like the multiplying by 2, equivalently (packedByte & 0x0F)-((packedByte & 0x08)<<1)